# I want to plot different horizontal line

Tags: pine-script

I want to plot different horizontal line base on % changes from Previous day close price.

I want to plot different horizontal line base on % changes from Previous day close price.
for example,
Previous day close price was 234.65, then
% Change that I want is upper side 1%, 2%, 3% from previous day close.
% Change that I want is down side -1%, -2%, -3% from previous day close.

Plot horizontal line at 237, 239.35, 241.70 at upper side.
Plot horizontal line at 232.30, 229.95, 227.60 at down side.